# How to remove multiple files in C using wildcards?

Tags: c, file-io, wildcard

Is there any way in C to remove (using `remove()`) multiple files using a `*` (wildcards)? 
I have a set of files that all start with Index. For example: `Index1.txt`, `Index-39.txt` etc.
They all start with Index but I don't know what text follows. There are also other files in the same directory so deleting all files won't work.

I know you can read the directory, iterate each file name, read the the first 5 chars, compare and if it fits then delete, but, is there an easier way (this is what I currently do by the way)?

<sup>This is standard C, since the code runs on Linux and Windows.</sup>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you point out you could use diropen, dirread, dirclose to access the directory contents, a function of your own (or transform the wildcards into a regex and use a regex library) to match, and unlink to delete.

There isn't a standard way to do this easier.  There are likely to be libraries, but they won't be more efficient than what you're doing.  Typically a file finding function takes a callback where you provide the matching and action part of the code.  All you'd be saving is the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I always appreciate when people tells you when something cannot be done, instead of BS'ing you.

Comment: On Unix instead of converting the wildcards to regular expressions, you should use fnmatch (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fnmatch.html).

Comment: And on Windows, use [`PathMatchSpec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathmatchspecw)

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind being platform-specific, you could use the `system()` call:

```
system("del index*.txt"); // DOS
system("rm index*.txt"); // unix
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) is some documentation on the `system()` call, which is part of the standard C library (cstdlib).

Comment: `system` is implementation specific by definition, so I always add a rider to look up the relevant vendor documentation (if you can find it). Principle of least surprises.

Comment: Thanks, but system() is a security nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all the program does?  If so, let the command line do the wildcard expansion for you:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   while (argc--)
     remove(argv[argc]);
}
```

on Windows, you need to link against 'setargv.obj', included in the VC standard lib directory.