# c++17 filesystem::remove_all with wildcard path

Tags: c++, c++17, embedded-linux

I want to delete all files, folders and subfolders but not the parent folder.

So I tried to use filesystem::remove_all with a wildcard, but this doesn't seems to work.

```
filesystem::removeall("pathtofolder/*");
```

There is no exception, but it doesn't delete anything.

Are wildcards are not allowed?

Do I really need  to call for each file and folder inside of `pathtofolder` the `removeall` method?

Comment: you could remove everything with removeall and then just recreate the folder you just  deleted to get that behaviour

Comment: "There is no exception" As shown in the documentation linked to by Ted's comment, errors are shown by the return value, not an exception: "Returns the number of files and directories that were deleted (which may be zero if p did not exist to begin with)."

Comment: Globbing (wildcards) is not supported by any well-designed **API** (other than [one specific to that purpose](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html)).  It’s an *interface* concern, and you don’t want arguments that result from prior processing (*e.g.*, quote removal, if you support that) to be interpreted as *user* input (what if a file were named `dir/*`?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Are wildcards are not allowed?*

There is no support for [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (wildcards) in  [`std::filesystem::remove_all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove):

> Deletes the contents of `p` (if it is a directory) and the contents of all its subdirectories, recursively, then deletes `p` itself as if by repeatedly applying the POSIX `remove`. Symlinks are not followed (symlink is removed, not its target)

> *Do I really need to call for each file and folder inside of pathtofolder the removeall method?*

Yes, your call should therefore be something like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <exception>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>

int main() {
    try {
        std::uintmax_t count = 0;

        // loop over all the "directory_entry"'s in "pathtofolder":
        for(auto& de : std::filesystem::directory_iterator("pathtofolder")) {
            // returns the number of deleted entities since c++17:
            count += std::filesystem::remove_all(de.path());
        }
        std::cout << "deleted " << count << " files and directories\n";

    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        // The overloads that does not take a std::error_code& parameter throws
        // filesystem_error on underlying OS API errors, constructed with p as
        // the first path argument and the OS error code as the error code
        // argument.

        // directory_iterator:  throws if the directory doesn't exist
        // remove_all:          does NOT throw if the path doesn't exist

        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that if `de.path()` doesn't exist, it's *not* an OS API error and it will not `throw` an exception. It will return `0` deleted files and directories (or `false` prior to C++17).

However, `directory_iterator()` will throw a `filesystem_error` if `pathtofolder` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

@TedLyngmo offers a valid solution; I typically add these things into a utility header, e.g. in my `src/util/filesystem.hpp` I put:

```
namespace util {
namespace filesystem {

std::uintmax_t remove_all_inside(const std::filesystem::path& dir) {
    std::uintmax_t removed_items_count { 0 };

    if (not is_directory(dir)) { 
        throw std::invalid_argument("Not a directory: " + dir.str());
    }
    for(auto& dir_element : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir)) {
        removed_items_count += std::filesystem::remove_all(dir_element .path());
    }
    return removed_items_count;
}

} // namespace filesystem
} // namespace util
```

and then I can write:

```
#include <util/filesystem.hpp>

// ... etc etc ...

util::filesystem::remove_all_inside("/path/to/folder");
```

A nice aspect of this approach is that it can work with earlier versions of the standard - you just use some preprocessor magic to choose either `std::filesystem` or `boost::filesystem` based on the C++ version; but the code using the utility function stays the same.

Comment: I was inspired by this so you got my vote and I built a `regex` based filter to provide an alternative to globbing, but when I was done I thought - "hey, `ranges` must have this" and tried a bit to put a ranges-based example together, like `directory_iterator("dir") | view(filter)` sort of, but I failed getting it working properly. A brute force iterator with a regex worked fine though.

Comment: I think a layer of function which mimics the std::filesystem API but takes shell-style globs instead of individual paths would be a nice thing to publish. Same for a regular expressions instead of globs. However... I seem to remember the C++ standard libraries' regex implementations are still flakey.

Comment: I made my iterator take a functor so one could put whatever in it. Kind of nice. No idea if they are flakey. I've only used them on SO sometime :-) When `consexpr` appears, I may rethink and start using them.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```cpp
std::wregex regExpName { LR"(^.*\.tmp$)" };
const auto tmpPath { std::filesystem::temp_directory_path() };
for (const auto& element : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(tmpPath))
    if (not element.is_directory() and std::regex_match(element.path().filename().wstring(), regExpName))
        std::filesystem::remove(element.path());
```

Answer (score -1):

I think wildcards are not allowed,

from the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) it seems that std::filesystem::remove/remove_all map to unlink/rmdir on POSIX systems and DeleteFileW/RemoveDirectoryW on Windows.

Both don't accept wildcards.

See:
[How to remove multiple files in C using wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156211/how-to-remove-multiple-files-in-c-using-wildcards)

[How to use DeleteFile with wildcard in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060534/how-to-use-deletefile-with-wildcard-in-c)

Comment: The non-standard solutions mentioned in "_How to remove multiple files in C using wildcards_" are absolutely not needed in modern C++. Neither are those listed in the other link which is for Windows only.